# passing the search query into html title tag

Tags: templating, variable

I wish to show the search query inside the page template but my logic seems to be off and just shows {{ query }} as a string.

What's the best way to achieve this?

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set title = "Search results for: {{ query }}" %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
{% set title = "Search results for: " ~ query %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up changing the title to a block within my layout template and doing thus:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% block title %}Search results for: {{query}}{% endblock %}
```